# XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class `Ticket` into xml. I get the error :"XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex type" because of my customfield class.

This is how the xml for customfields should look like ( the attribute array is nesseray but I don't understand how to create it):

```
<custom_fields type="array">
<custom_field name="Standby Reason" id="6">
<value/>
</custom_field>
<custom_field name="Close Date" id="84">
```

**Class Ticket**

```
public class Ticket
{
    [XmlElement("custom_fields")]
    public CustomFields Custom_fields { get; set; }
```

**Class CustomFields**

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomFields
{
    [XmlAttribute("array")]
    public List<CustomField> custom_field { get; set; }
```

**Class CustomField**

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomField
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Value { get; set; }
```

**Serialize Method**

```
public string Serialize(object obj)
{
    var nsSerializer = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    nsSerializer.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ticket), String.Empty);

    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        ExtendedXmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new ExtendedXmlTextWriter(writer);
        serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj, nsSerializer);

        //return writer.ToString();

        XElement root = new XElement("custom_fields", new XAttribute("type", "array"),
            new XElement("custom_field",
                new XAttribute("name", "Standby Reason"),
                new XAttribute("id", 6)
                ), new XElement("value"),
                    new XElement("custom_field",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Close Date"),
                        new XAttribute("id", 84)
                        )
                        );

        return (writer.ToString() + root.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes Linq To Xml can be very helpful

```
XElement root = new XElement("ticket",
                        new XElement("custom_fields",
                            new XAttribute("type", "array"),
                            new XElement("custom_field",
                                new XAttribute("name", "Standby Reason"),
                                new XAttribute("id", 6)
                            ),
                            new XElement("value"),
                            new XElement("custom_field",
                                new XAttribute("name", "Close Date"),
                                new XAttribute("id", 84)
                            )
                        )
                );

string xml = root.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
<ticket>
  <custom_fields type="array">
    <custom_field name="Standby Reason" id="6" />
    <value />
    <custom_field name="Close Date" id="84" />
  </custom_fields>
</ticket>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that my class Ticket is large an contains other elements. I use another class inheriting "ISerializer" which does the convertion. Is there a way I can add the linq part to it?

Comment: @ConradC How about using other part in Linq? `root.Add(new XElement(...));` etc....

Comment: I understand the principle, but I need to add the other part within <ticket>.
I tried this but no sucess:
new XElement(writer),
                        new XElement("custom_fields",
                            new XAttribute("type", "array"),

Comment: @ConradC `XElement.Parse`, `XElement.Load`, but if possible don't mix XmlSerializer and Linq2Xml

Answer (score 1):

Class Ticket

```
public class Ticket
{
    [XmlElement("custom_fields")]
    public CustomFields Custom_fields { get; set; }
```

Class CustomFields

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomFields
{
    [XmlArray("array"), XmlArrayItem("custom_field")]
    public List<CustomField> custom_field { get; set; }
```

Class CustomField

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomField
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
```

XML:

```
<ticket>
   <custom_fields>
     <array>
        <custom_field name="Standby Reason" id="6"><value /></custom_field>
        <custom_field name="Close Date" id="84"><value /></custom_field>
     </array>
   </custom_fields>
</ticket>
```

Comment: It does not work. 
I mentionned above that I need the attribute array like so <custom_fields type="array">.
Not a subelement.

Answer (score 0):

List<CustomField> can not be XML attribute.

Comment: What is the way around?
How can I serialize my class?

Comment: Insted [XmlAttribute("array")] write [XmlElement("array")]. In XML file you should use tag "array".

Comment: Sorry, insted XmlAttribute("array") use XmlArray("array")